# Why send "Bearer" text in Header

Tags: oauth-2.0, bearer-token

It has always been haunting me but i can't find the answer.
When sending bearer token, why does one send the "Bearer" string also usually (i.e: Bearer abcd1234), isnt it enough with just the token only?

Answer (score 2):

The `Authorization` header can be used with different authorize schemes like `Basic` or `Digest`. The `Bearer` scheme indicates that you are using a [bearer token](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/).

The HTTP authorization scheme can be extended with custom schemes.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617 for more information